# SQL SELECT MAX(Id)

Tags: php, python, mysql, select, max

I try to make a graph of the 7 last entries of my SQL database.
So I tried to select the maximum (or last entered) id number, but it is not working.

My table:

```
Id   | id_time | temp   | RH
2700 | 2706    | 24.187 | 63.0999984741211
2701 | 2707    | 24.25  | 63
2702 | 2708    | 26.562 | 99.9000015258789
2703 | 2709    | 25     | 50.456
2704 | 2710    | 28.2   | 64.48
2705 | 2711    | 21.541 | 78.45876
2706 | 2712    | 18.567 | 55.787455465
2707 | 2713    | 23.25  | 58.54564
2708 | 2714    | 26.5   | 49.9000015258789
2709 | 2715    | 25     | 50.456
2710 | 2716    | 28.2   | 64.48
2711 | 2717    | 21.541 | 78.45876
2712 | 2718    | 18.567 | 55.787455465
2713 | 2719    | 23.25  | 58.54564
2714 | 2720    | 26.5   | 49.9000015258789
```

The python code that I used to make the tables:

```
with con:
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tijd")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE tijd(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
             jaar VARCHAR(25), \
             maand VARCHAR(25), \
             dag VARCHAR(25), \
             uur VARCHAR(25), \
             minuut VARCHAR(25))")
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE data(Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
             id_tijd VARCHAR(25), \
             temp VARCHAR(25), \
             RH VARCHAR(25))")
```

The php code that I use to select the data from the database:

```
        <?php
       $dbhost = 'localhost';
       $dbuser = 'testuser1';
       $dbpass = 'loes';

       $conn1 = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

       if(! $conn1 ) {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
       }


       $sql1 ='SELECT MAX(Id) FROM data';
       mysql_select_db('huygendb');
       $retval1 = mysql_query( $sql1, $conn1 );

       if(! $retval1 ) {
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
       }

       $max1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die ("no query");
       echo "{$max1} <br>";
       if ($max1-7 > 0){
        $max = $max1 -7;}
       else{
        $max = 0;}
       echo "{$max} <br>";

       mysql_close($conn1);
       ?>
```

The result of the code is:

```
Resource id #3
0
```

There might be still somewhere a record with Id = 3, so I guessed my Id's are strings (because '3' is higher than '2714'), but I really thought I made them integers right?
How can I fix the php code to do what I want?

Comment: Don't use PHP's mysql_ API.

Comment: Why? Because it's been found to emit signals that slockly suck your mind out through your navel rendering void any ability you may previously have had to use a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_query(); returns a resource, not a result set. you need to fetch data from it:

```
   $res = mysql_query($sql1) or die ("no query");
   $max1 = mysql_fetch_array($res);
   var_dump($max1);
```

And then: don't use mysql_* functions. They are deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

First check php docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). mysql_query returns a resource not an object or array. To check the result set from database you need to loop through it like

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($max1)) {
echo $row['Id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking for sql query, the following query will order by column name in descending fashion and return 7 rows

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name DESC LIMIT 7;
```